# Passing a pointer to a function in C

Tags: c

Function declaration is

```
void function (char *);
```

If p is a char pointer then what is difference between these two function calls.

```
function (p)
```

and

```
function ((char **) &p)
```

Are they both same.

I would be thankful to the stack overflow family for any information on this topic.

Comment: `void function ((char **) &p)` is not a valid function declaration ...

Comment: Sorry dragosht I agree with your point so I have edited my question now.

Comment: @dragosht: `function ((char **) &p)` is a function-call, not a function-declaration.

Comment: @barakmanos: See the edit history (which also explains the answers).

Comment: @mafso: Oh, ok, got it :)

Comment: maybe (*((char **) &p)) ? Because here first call is for *char and second is for **char

Comment: But there is & before p Ivan

Comment: Yes. &p of pointer is pointer to pointer. but function asks for just a pointer. Or there are two different functions? there is no difference except that you pass different data foo((char*) &p);.

Comment: I have seen such kind of calls but that's true for different data type then why don't you just type cast it with (type *)p and send it? Why use such calls?

Comment: there is difference INSIDE function, because it can process 2d arrays, in second case, for example. But yes, you can cast without warnings everything to everything, for example, array to structure.

Comment: Could you explain a little more on your previous comment Ivan.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60161/discussion-between-adarsh-and-ivan-ivanov).

Answer (score 1):

`void function ((char **) &p)` if my memory is not cheating me is not valid C syntax. The closest you can get to the validity is to remove the inner `(` and `)` and compile as C++ an then it would be a reference to a pointer of a char pointer.

The first one is just a "plain" char pointer.

Comment: "if memory serves correctly" is more grammatically correct.

Answer (score 1):

When you call:

```
function(p);
```

the code of `function` can read in the location pointed to by `p` the contents of a `char` array (i.e. a string), or a single `char` variable or whatever data it expects.

When you call:

```
function((char **) &p);
```

the compiler will complain with:

```
warning: incompatible pointer types passing 'char **' to parameter of
  type 'char *'
```

because `&p` is of type `char **` (in fact, the explicit conversion `(char **)` is unnecessary), i.e. a pointer to a pointer to `char` while in the function declaration there is `char *` i.e. pointer to `char`.
On runtime, `function` will not read a string or a single character as it may expect, but will read the bytes of a pointer to `char` as if they were a string (potentially causing a crash).

Answer (score -1):

Your idea is good: the operators `*` and `&` cancel each other when assigning values, but not in  declarations, just like `*` and `/`, but the header:

```
void function ((char **) &p);
```

can't be compiled by a C compiler.

Comment: `*` and `&` are not operators in this context, they are parts of a declarator. `void function(char *&p);` would not be valid either.